# How to calculate and display 4 other days from the day i add in date picker and set local notification to it?

Tags: xcode, nsdate, localnotification

In my App, When i select a day in the datepicker it should automatically calculate and display 4 other days and also it should notify on the corresponding days. For Eg. if i enter 19-08-2014, it should calculate and display the 3rd day, the 7th day, the 14th day and the 21st day from 19-08-2014(the day i entered in datepicker).

How would i achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
I have added my current code for your reference. This doesnt serve my purpose.
Kindly Help.

```
(IBAction)save:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.picker date];
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    //localNotif.alertBody = _enterText.text;
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Please Take Your Rabipur Dosage";
    localNotif.fireDate = pickerDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotif.soundName = (UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName);
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    //localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: What is happening with your current code. You show what you are looking for but not what is happening.

Comment: My current code only displays the day i enter for notification. but i want it to display the 3rd,7th 14th and 21st day from the day i enter and also shoot notification on those days.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSDateComponents` object with the date difference you want to add, and add it to `pickerDate` via `NSCalendar -dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options`. Then create your notification based on the resulting date.

In this case, something like this:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:3];
NSDate *reminderDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:pickerDate options:0];
```

Repeat for 7th, 14th, and 21st day.

Comment: Hi,Thank for your reply. I will try this code and let you know.

Comment: Hi, im not good in xcode programming. Can u please tell me where to add the code hat u have mentioned previously.

Comment: No. This is very, very, very simple. If you can't figure it out, then there is no limit to what I'm going to have to explain to you to write your program. Perhaps you should take a class or read some books before you dive into writing code.